# Faster Alternatives to cp -l for a Whole File Structure?

Tags: shell, backup, rsync, cp

Okay, so I need to create a copy of a file-structure, however the structure is huge (millions of files) and I'm looking for the fastest way to copy it.

I'm currently using `cp -lR "$original" "$copy"` however even this is extremely slow (takes several hours).

I'm wondering if there are any faster methods I can use? I know of `rsync --link-dest` but this isn't any quicker, but really I'd want it to be quicker as I want to create these snap-shots every hour or-so.

The alternative is copying only changes (which I can find quickly) into each folder then "flattening" them when I need to free up space (rsync newer folders into older ones until the last complete snapshot is reached), but I would really rather that each folder be its own complete snapshot.

Comment: Consider using a file system that supports snapshots natively, like btrfs or zfs. They can snapshot in seconds with minimal disk cost.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you discarding link-dest? I use a script with that option and take snapshots pretty often and the performance is pretty good.

In case you reconsider, here's the script I use: https://github.com/alvaroreig/varios/blob/master/incremental_backup.sh

Comment: Oh I'm not saying it's a bad option, but if that's all I'm doing then `cp -lR` should have less overhead than `rsync`, I was just wondering if there were any faster methods as for a very large structure even `cp -lR` can be extremely slow. The main advantage of `rsync` is that you can do other stuff at the same time with a single command, such as copying in updated files in addition to linking the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pax` installed, you can use it. Think of it as tar or cpio, but standard, per POSIX.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Move "somedir/tree" to "$odir/tree".
itree=$1
odir=$2
base_tree=$(basename "$itree")
pax -rw "$itree" -s "#$itree#$base_tree#g" "$odir"
```

The `-s replstr` is an unfortunate necessity (you'll get $odir/$itree otherwise), but it works nicely, and it has been quicker than cp for large structures thus far.

tar is of course another option if you don't have pax as one person suggested already.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the files, you may achieve performance gains by compressing:

```
cd "$original && tar zcf - . | (cd "$copy" && tar zxf -)
```

This creates a tarball of the "original" directory, sends the data to stdout, then changes to the "copy" directory (which must exist) and untars the incoming stream.

For the extraction, you may want to watch the progress: `tar zxvf -`

Comment: could you explain why tar,gzip,gunzip,untar should be faster than simply copying the files?

Comment: @glenn I'm not sure how that could be faster than `cp -lR` which only creates hard-links and doesn't actually copy anything at all (except to create new directories)? The overhead in my case does seem to be the size of the hierarchy, so you're not wrong that reducing it to a single file in advance could be an option, but not in my case unfortunately, which means I'd be tarring the same huge hierarchy and wasting space overall.